# Manipulate plot using smacof funcition

Tags: r, mds

I am trying to do some MDS analysis using the *eurodist* dataset, however when I plot the configurations I get un upside-down graph:

[image: Upside-Down Europe map]

When I am on classical MDS I can obviate to this by make a reflection on the x-axis with:

```
X2D=cmdscale(EurDistances, k = 2, eig = TRUE, add = FALSE, x.ret = FALSE)
X2D
require(graphics) 
x = X2D$points[,1]
y = X2D$points[,2]
plot(x, -y, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", main="cmdscale(eurodist)")
text(x, -y, rownames(X2D$points), cex=0.8)
```

Thus I am able to produce the right map:

[image: Europe Map]

However, when I do metric MDS is not that obvious to me how to get the x and y points from the **smacofSym** function and so I don't know how to correct the upside-downess of the plot after the following piece of code:

```
resm.EurDistances=smacofSym(EurDistances,2)
resm.EurDistances
summary(resm.EurDistances)
plot(resm.EurDistances, main="smacofSym(eurociti,2)")
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The configuration matrix is stored in `config` (see `?smacofSym`) so `x <- resm.EurDistances$conf[, 1] ; y <- resm.EurDistances$conf[, 2]` should do it. Use your plot/text commands from your cmdscale example.

Comment: I was running a flawed code and this solution wasn't working, thank you for getting  me back on the right path!! Solved!